# numerical integration of exponential which contains complex function

Tags: matlab, numerical-modelling

I would like to get the result of Fresnel-Kirchhoff integral in paraxial approximation to the cylindrical diffracted wave and here is a part of my code and if it is solved gonna be carrying the other parts out. It is a Matlab code.

```
vpa(int(exp(-1i*2*k*(n_cl-n_s)*sqrt(b^2-x_p^2))*exp(1i*k*((x-x_p)^2)/2z),-b,-a))
```

with respect to x_p. where

```
b = 62.5*e-6; % cladding radius
a = 4*e-6; % core radius
n_co = 1.473; % core ref index
n_cl = n_co - 0.016; % cladding ref index
n_s  = 1.37868e-5; % surrounding ref index
L = 457.9e-9; % wavelength
k = 2*pi/L; % wavenumber
z = 0.4 ; 
x =-0.0002;
```

Which command should be used as an integrator? I've been trying to use `int()` instead of `quad` since `quad` doesn't fulfill the requirement to obtain complex results. In addition to that I've been getting the well-known error of

```
Explicit integral could not be found
```

Don't know what to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) function (more precisely `sym/int`) is mainly designed for symbolic integration. When it cannot obtain a symbolic result it will attempt a numeric solution using MuPAD's [`numeric::int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-int.html). I don't know why this won't evaluate to a numeric result, but you can use MuPAD's [`numeric::quadrature`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-quadrature.html), which underlies `numeric::int`:

```
evalin(symengine,'numeric::quadrature(exp(-(pi*(4722366482869645/1208925819614629174706176 - x_p^2)^(1/2)*55043382873750776053760*i)/4324743225012021)*exp(((x_p + 1/5000)^2*7366803725989309*i)/2684354560), x_p == -1/16000..-4722366482869645/1180591620717411303424)')
```

However, based on all of your floating-point parameter values, I'd imagine that a numeric [quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_(mathematics))-based solution is what you're actually looking for. You should be using [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) (or possibly [`quadgk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html) in older versions of Matlab):

```
integral(@(x_p)exp(-1i*2*k*(n_cl-n_s)*sqrt(b^2-x_p.^2)).*exp(1i*k*((x-x_p).^2)/2*z),-b,-a)
```

Results returned by both methods agree with each other.

NOTE: there's a typo in your equation. I've assumed that you meant `...)/2*z` as opposed to `...)/(2*z)`.

Comment: thanks a lot . I will try to use quadgk. It is accurate to say that quadgk works.